# Error while installing apache with puppet-apache module

Tags: puppet, apache-2.4, puppetmaster

I am using puppet lab's [apache module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apache) for installing and configuring apache. I am using Debian 7 (wheezy) and below is the manifest file I am use as `site.pp` in puppet-master. And from the puppet client I am executing `puppet apply --test` to install the apache. But I am getting error.

```
node 'debian.yaalie.com' {
    class {'apache': }

    apache::vhost { 'debian.yaalie.com':
    port => '80',
    docroot => '/var/www/'
    }
}
```

***Error:***

```
Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install apache2' returned 100: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apache2-mpm-worker apache2-utils apache2.2-common
Suggested packages:
  apache2-doc apache2-suexec apache2-suexec-custom
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-mpm-worker apache2-utils apache2.2-common
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 53 not upgraded.
Need to get 459 kB of archives.
After this operation, 933 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  apache2-utils apache2.2-common apache2-mpm-worker apache2
E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes
```

Actually the error is because I have multiple dependency files that are not getting installed automatically. How to solve this issue.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Puppet or dependencies.
The problem is that it appears that your system is missing keys to verify package signatures.
You should fix that.

```
apt-get install debian-keyring
apt-get install debian-archive-keyring
apt-get update
```

Could possibly fix that.
If it doesn't, read https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt